# Prefer unordered_set over vector

Tags: c++, stl

Is it safe to say that if I don't want duplicates in my container, and I don't care about element position as I only want to iterate through the container, then I should use an `unordered_set` instead of `vector`?

Comment: Probably not. `vector` is fast and is the best choice 99% of the time.

Comment: Unless, of course, if correctness is more important than performance, then use `unordered_set` and switch to `vector` only if performance problems arise from the use of `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it safe to say that if I don't want duplicates in my container, and I don't care about element position as I only want to iterate through the container, then I should use an unordered_set instead of vector?

No, it is not. It depends on many factors. For example if you seldom add new elements but iterate over container quite often it would be preferable to use `std::vector` and maintain uniqueness manually. There also could be other factors affecting your decision. But normally yes you may prefer `std::unordered_set` as it simplifies your program.

Comment: So if I need to iterate through the vector very often, I should use `std::vector` with an approach like [this](http://pastebin.com/5bYrig3K) for inserting items?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access pastebin from work. There are many approaches. You may keep `std::vector` sorted by instering via `std::lower_bound`, you may create index if original order of data is important. It depends on data and requirements.

Comment: Here's the function I wrote in the above link: `void pushback(std::vector<int> &vec, int item)
{
        if(std::find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), item) == vec.cend())
                vec.push_back(item);
}`

Comment: That lookup is pretty ineffective, but in some situation could be sufficient. All depends on particular situation.

Comment: How else can I avoid having duplicates?

Comment: You can keep vector sorted using `std::lower_bound` to check and insert new element: `auto f = std::lower_bound( vec.begin(), vec.end(), item ); if( f == vec.end() || *f != item ) vec.insert( f, item );` - insertion will be slower but lookup significantly faster. Again all depends on data and requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely. `unordered_set`s are not required to be contiguous containers; in the case where you'd frequently want to read <s>all</s> numerous values contained in the set, you may prefer `std::vector` on time-critic application.

[`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set):

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to individual elements, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the exact bucket the element is placed into.

But in the general case, I'd say Yes.

Answer (score 4):

I generally prefer vector or map. (or in your case, std::set).

Hash tables can be faster than maps/sets (red-black trees), but red-black trees have guaranteed performance 100% of the time. And logarithmic performance is REALLY fast! A hash table kan kill performance when it starts rehashing.

std::vector is the workhorse of the STL and should be your default choice. Vector is very straightforward, and is very cache-friendly

Comment: How can vector be OP's choice if they want to eliminate duplicates? Did you really read the question, or are simply copying-pasting internet wisdom?

Comment: @SergeyA If iterating is the main objective, and it's performed relatively often in comparison with insertion, then you can manually write the avoid-duplication logic when inserting into a vector (O(N)). You'll then gain when iterating, especially if you perform it multiple times.

Comment: @vsoftco, you really need an outrageous ratio of insertion vs iterations to justify vector over unordered_map. Especially taking into account that unordered map usually is a continguous object.

Comment: @SergeyA A good way not to have duplicates in a container is not to put duplicates in the container. If OP's *specifically* wants to protect itself from having duplicates, (s)he did not mention it.

Comment: @SergeyA: No, I am not copy-pasting internet wisdom. My advice is general, and it comes from my own thinking. If the particular quesion here does not fit with vector, I suggest using the red-black tree-based structures and not hash table.

Comment: @ErikAlapää, and that suggestion is based specifically on what?

Comment: @SergeyA  Like I said, hash tables are more efficient than rb-trees in 99% of the cases, but sometimes you want 100%. So I almost always prefer rb-trees.

Comment: @ErikAlapää, I fail to understand. You are saying that in 99% of the time hash is faster than a tree. That means, in 1% trees are faster - yet you prefer trees? Why choose 1% over 99%?

Comment: @SergeyA It is about very fast worst-case performance. rb-trees are logarithmic 100% of the time, hash tables have constant-time speed 99% of the time but much worse worst-case performance. And logarithmic speed is very fast, fast enough for most uses. For example, in a hard real-time system, worst-case performance is the most important property to consider.

Comment: @ErikAlapää, I think, it is a premature pessimization, but I understand your point now.

Answer (score 1):

This article by Matt Austern is related to this topic and it is worth reading:

[Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead) by Matt Austern](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf)

This thread is trying to identify conditions under which unordered_set is preferable over vectors. Similarly, in the above article, the author clearly identifies four conditions, which all need to be satisfied in order to prefer set over a custom but simpler data structure called sorted_vector (last section: What is set good for?). Like that it will be interesting to identify a set of conditions for preferring unordered_set over vector.

also, the last paragraph of the article summarizes a useful rule to keep in mind:

> Every component in the standard C++ library is there because it's useful for some purpose, but sometimes that purpose is narrowly defined and rare. As a general rule you should always use the simplest data structure that meets your needs. The more complicated a data structure, the more likely that it's not as widely useful as it might seem.

Answer (score -2):

Of course yes. If you do not want duplicates, you have to use a key-aware container, and since unordered_* totally win over their tree-based counterparts, this is pretty much your only choice.